# Selenium use Chromium instead of google-chrome

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, selenium, chromium

I first installed Chromium and prepared my Selenium tests to run with it (I have the chromeDriver and I did create the symbolic link google-chrome pointing to chromium-browser). Everything was running smooth.

Later I did install the google-chrome browser to debug some node.js application and since then Selenium opens Google Chrome instead of Chromium.

I can not figure out how to get back selenium opening Chromium.
The synmbolic link does exist and points to chromium-browser.

How to run Selenium with Chromium when google-chrome is also available on the system?

**UPDATE 1:** what about update-alternatives ?

```
$ ls -lah /usr/bin/google-chrome
/usr/bin/google-chrome -> /etc/alternatives/google-chrome

$ ls -lah /etc/alternatives/google-chrome
/etc/alternatives/google-chrome -> /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From [these docs](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver): "For Linux systems, the ChromeDriver expects /usr/bin/google-chrome to be a symlink to the actual Chrome binary. See also the section on overriding the Chrome binary location ." Unfortunately that section does not appear to exist on that page but I think I found it elsewhere: [executing in a non-standard location](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities#TOC-Using-a-Chrome-executable-in-a-non-standard-location), so that's the way to go:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("/path/to/other/chrome/binary");
```