# WebDriver can't start chromium within docker

Tags: selenium, docker, protractor

I wrote e2e-tests for an angularjs app with protractor. Everything works fine. But I want to run this tests within a docker container. In the docker container I started `Xvfb :0 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x24 &` and set the `DISPLAY=:0` environment. Chromium is also within the docker-image.
But something went wrong.

```
    protractor client/e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js --verbose

[13:14:40] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[13:14:40] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[13:14:42] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://172.17.0.2:50962/wd/hub

    /code/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/error.js:27
        super(opt_error);
        ^
    WebDriverError: null
        at WebDriverError (/code/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/error.js:27:5)
        at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/code/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/error.js:580:13)
        at /code/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:64:13
        at Promise.invokeCallback_ (/code/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1329:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (/code/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2790:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/code/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2773:21)
        at asyncRun (/code/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2652:27)
        at /code/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
    From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
        at acquireSession (/code/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:62:22)
        at Function.createSession (/code/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:295:12)
        at Builder.build (/code/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/builder.js:458:24)
        at Local.DriverProvider.getNewDriver (/code/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:37:33)
        at Runner.createBrowser (/code/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:182:43)
        at /code/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:255:30
        at _fulfilled (/code/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
        at self.promiseDispatch.done (/code/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
        at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/code/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
        at /code/node_modules/q/q.js:604:44
    [13:15:03] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
```

For me it seems that the chromedriver won't be started. I tried to start `protractor` with  `--stackTrace` and `--troubleshoot` but get not more info.

Answer (score 0):

The error `WebDriver : null` is because protractor cannot find chrome browser in the docker. You need to create a symlink to chromium browser that is already installed in the docker container. Have a look at [run selenium on chromium](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24999318/selenium-use-chromium-instead-of-google-chrome&ved=0ahUKEwjOksn__NLPAhWJO48KHSElDIwQFggdMAE&usg=AFQjCNGWwTJji0wxoZx-XG7_GHvng41shw) to make your scripts run on chromium browser.

Comment: That didn't help. Either setting symlink nor setting binary-path to chrome-options.

Comment: Which OS you are using?

Comment: Im using `Debian GNU/Linux 8.5 (jessie)` within the docker.