# Getting Error in Selenium/Python - chromedriver executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

First of all , i know that this question has been asked quite a lot here .Just making it clear that i have read most accepted answers and followed all steps properly , still getting this error as mentioned in question.
Here's my script down below along with all other information

*[ I am using selenium with chromedriver trying to use it with chromium browser in headless mode running ubuntu 20 ]*

**cat test.py**

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/chromium-browser'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
print(driver.title)
print ("Headless Chrome Initialized")
driver.quit()
```

**python3 test.py**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 72, in start                                           self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__           self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)       FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
                                                                       During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

**What steps i followed**

```
sudo apt install chromium-browser
python3 -m pip install selenium
wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/83.0.4103.39/chromedriver_linux64.zip
unzip chromedriver*
chmod +x chromedriver
sudo mv chromedriver /usr/local/bin/
sudo chown root:root /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
sudo chmod 0755 /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

**Verifying Everything together**

```
╭─[localhost] as xd003 in ~
╰─➤ lsb_release -a | grep Description && \
apt -qq list python3 && \
apt -qq list chromium-browser && \
which chromedriver && \
which chromium-browser && \
echo $PATH

No LSB modules are available.
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
python3/focal,now 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 arm64 [installed]
chromium-browser/focal-updates,now 81.0.4044.129-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 arm64 [installed]
/usr/local/bin/chromedriver
/usr/bin/chromium-browser
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Everything looks good me , can someone please suggest what am i doing wrong ?

The Ubuntu20 i am running locally is a Ubuntu Proot which i am using on my android device

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium using Python - Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)

Comment: i had already read the accepted answer there , only thing i did different was this step - export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/directory/of/executable/downloaded/in/previous/step ... instead of this i did sudo mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin/ although this should ideally definitely work

Comment: I haven't realized you explicitly put `/usr/local/bin/geckodriver` path as argument, my bad.

Comment: I see you did a `chmod +x`, are you sure it was with the same user running the Python script?

Comment: @Arount yes definitely , i am the only user

Comment: Could you update your whole code to `import os; print(os.path.isfile('/usr/local/bin/geckodriver'))`, execute it and give me the output pls?

Comment: @Arount sure ╭─[localhost] as xd003 in ~                                            ╰─➤ cat test2.py
import os; print(os.path.isfile('/usr/local/bin/geckodriver'))%        
╭─[localhost] as xd003 in ~
╰─➤ python3 test2.py
True

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216483/discussion-between-arount-and-sachin).

Comment: Is `/usr/local/bin` on your PATH? You just need to make sure it is, since that's where you put `chromedriver`.

Comment: @BryanOakley yes sir , it is     ╭─[localhost] as xd003 in ~
╰─➤ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

Comment: Also updated in question - verification section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After days of figuring this out , i finally was able to get this error fixed.

So as i had mentioned i am running Prooted Ubuntu 20 on Android Device . Now here the linux kernel architecture being aarch64 seems not supported by the official chrome webdriver - https://chromedriver.chromium.org

To fix this , just download a chromedriver compiled for arm64 variant .You can always get the latest one from here - https://github.com/electron/electron/releases

In short , everything else was perfect ,just needed to replace the wget link by - https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v8.3.4/chromedriver-v8.3.4-linux-arm64.zip

PS / Maybe if the error was something like - linux kernel architecture not supported , it would have been lot easier to fix it but nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

1. chromedriver I always pass to constructor
2. PATH error occurs if it cannot be found (see example below where I deliberately pass incorrect param)
3. this driver does not work with chromium,  only chrome.  Hence reason to keep drivers separate from `/usr/bin` dir

```
import time, os, datetime, json, requests, re, subprocess
from distutils.version import StrictVersion
from pathlib import Path
import xmlplain
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

def get_release(v):
    r = re.compile(f'^(83\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+).*linux.*$')
    maxrel = "0.0.0"
    pos = 0
    for i, rel in enumerate(v):
        if r.match(rel) is not None and StrictVersion(r.split(rel)[1]) > StrictVersion(maxrel): 
            maxrel = r.split(rel)[1]
            pos = i

    return v[pos]

def cmd(cmd:str, assertfail=True) :
    up = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, close_fds=True)
    str = [l.rstrip().decode() for l in up.stdout]
    exitcode = up.wait()
    if assertfail: assert exitcode == 0, f"[{exitcode}] {cmd} {str}"
    return exitcode,  str


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # os.environ["DISPLAY"] = ":0.0"

    # find latest driver available
    resp = requests.get("https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com")
    raw = xmlplain.xml_to_obj(resp.content, strip_space=True, fold_dict=False)
    v = get_release([e["Contents"][0]["Key"] for e in raw["ListBucketResult"] if "Contents" in e.keys()])
    # download if required
    if not Path.cwd().joinpath(v.split("/")[0]).is_dir():
        cmd(f"mkdir {v.split('/')[0]}")
        cmd(f"wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/{v} -O {v}")
        cmd(f"unzip {v} -d {v.split('/')[0]}/")
    # hit a webpage
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(f"unknown/chromedriver")  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
    except selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException as e:
        print(e)
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/chromium-browser'
    options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/google-chrome'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(f"{v.split('/')[0]}/chromedriver", options=options)  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
    driver.get('https://www.google.com')
    print(driver.title)
    print ("Headless Chrome Initialized")
    driver.quit()
```

output:

```
Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Google
Headless Chrome Initialized
```

Comment: You said chromedriver doesn't work with chromium but I have seen many people here on SO asking about it and many using it as well probably. Here are 2 such questions where answers with decent upvotes have suggested that we can use chromium browser instead of chrome - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731953/use-selenium-with-chromium-browser https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24999318/selenium-use-chromium-instead-of-google-chrome.

Comment: Also read my solution , i think chromedriver was wrongly outputting it needs to be in path when it should have rightly said - linux kernel architecture not supported.   Anyways thanks for your input

Comment: Both your points are correct.  When chromedriver is incompatible with browser produced errors quite often do not say this.   When I use this chromedriver with chromium I get an DevToolsActivePort error but not a compatibility error and not PATH error.  Drivers also need to be compiled for architecture - raspberry pi requires a driver compiled for ARM processors. This you have noted as well.  IMHO get working with chrome then move to chromium knowing there is work to find an appropriately built driver.

Comment: yeah i would have used chrome if possible but in the prooted ubuntu20 i am running , chrome can't be installed by any means. Anyways finally got it solved by using a arm64 chromedriver and that too with chromium . For that devtools error which you mentioned i was facing it few days back ,i solved it by adding these 2 lines

Comment: options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")